# How to stream video on my video view from samba server ? How can I do it

Tags: android, android-videoview, samba, jcifs, nanohttpd

I am stuck at this since very long and not getting any proper solution for it.
I am using jcifs and samba to access shared folder from my windows Pc. Now I want to play the video file which I am getting from the shared folder. I have searched with every keyword but not getting anything what to do and how to do.

**Till now I have seen these links:**

- [Using NanoHTTPD in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309256/using-nanohttpd-in-android)
- [how to stream video from internet via nanoHTTPd to VideoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694374/how-to-stream-video-from-internet-via-nanohttpd-to-videoview)
- [Android SDK : Samba server streaming video to Android using VideoView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929880/android-sdk-samba-server-streaming-video-to-android-using-videoview)

None of these were found promising.

**Then I searched more for it
and I found this :**

- https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-smb-streaming/

**This is my code to get the files from my windows shared folder**

```
            String ip = "192.108.0.00";
            String username = "test";
            String sharedFolder = "andsyyy/";

            String path = "smb://" + ip + "/" + sharedFolder;
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", username, null);
            SmbFile sfile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
            String[] files = sfile.list();
             PATH = sfile.getPath();// returns path of folder

            for (String fileName : files) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Fisier: " + fileName);

                abc = fileName;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            z = ex.getMessage();
        }
        return z;
    }
```