# Videoview, mediaplayer not resuming video on onResume

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I an new to Android/Java and have been struggling to play video from the left over position before putting the app in background. I have read several posts outlining overriding onPause and onResume but unfortunately I cant seem to get any working. Right now all the videos play just fine except that if I put the app in BG and open it back again the video starts from beginning rather than resuming from where it was left. This is my code, please help.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class VideoPlayback extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = Dashboard.class.getSimpleName();
    ProgressBar progressBar = null;
    VideoView vidView;
    int pos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_playback);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(Dashboard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        String link = "http://" + message;
        vidView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(link);
        Log.d(TAG, link);
        vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        try {
            MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
            vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
            vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        vidView.requestFocus();
        vidView.start();
        progressBar.setVisibility(vidView.VISIBLE);

        vidView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1, int arg2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d(TAG, "Changed");
                        progressBar.setVisibility(vidView.GONE);
                        mp.start();
                    }
                });

            }

        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if(String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode())=="4"){
            finish();
            Log.v("key pressed", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "PAUSE");
        vidView.pause();
        pos=vidView.getCurrentPosition();
        Log.d("POS",String.valueOf(pos));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "Resume");
        Log.d("R_POS", String.valueOf(pos));
        vidView.seekTo(pos);
        //vidView.resume();
    }


}
```

Comment: which position you get in "R_POS" when resume activity?

Comment: save value as in pause, the same value is passed.

Comment: but you got that value? if pause on 457 and on Resume get pos = 457

Comment: Yes, I got the same in  Resume which I got in Pause.

Comment: try to set this in onResume videoPlayer.requestFocus();
videoPlayer.seekTo(position);
videoPlayer.start();

Comment: tried....no luck, same result

Comment: so I just came to know that when the app in but in BG `pos` would be lost. Given this I decided to store pos in shared prefs and use it in on resume. This is the code: http://pastebin.com/76F7VbKK. I got the pos saved in the saved instance and the value is being passed to onPause and onResume. The issue now is that when I re open the app I see the seek bar where I left it before putting the app in BG but rather than starting from there it goes back to beginning and starts the video again

Comment: Found this related to my problem but this seems a lot of work; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987042/videoview-onresume-loses-buffered-portion-of-the-video

Answer (score 0):

Ok , so finally I got this going, one of the issues was that the video position upon pause was getting lost when app was going in background so I used onSaveInstanceState to retain the value and secondly the video I was streaming was `.mp4` but was not seekable. Once I started using `H.264` encoding everything fell in to place. Here is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;    

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.os.PowerManager;


    public class VideoPlayback extends Activity {
        private static final String TAG = Dashboard.class.getSimpleName();
        //protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

        ProgressBar progressBar = null;
        VideoView vidView;
        int pos;

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            pos = vidView.getCurrentPosition();
            vidView.pause();
            outState.putInt("position", pos);
            Log.d("SAVED-POS", String.valueOf(pos));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if ( savedInstanceState != null ){
                pos = savedInstanceState.getInt("pos");
            }
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_playback);
           getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(Dashboard.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            String link = "http://" + message;
            vidView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
            Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(link);
            Log.d(TAG, link);
            vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
            try {
                MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
                vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
                vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            vidView.requestFocus();
            vidView.start();
            progressBar.setVisibility(vidView.VISIBLE);

            vidView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();

                    mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1, int arg2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Log.d(TAG, "Changed");
                            progressBar.setVisibility(vidView.GONE);
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    });

                }

            });

        }
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            if(String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode())=="4"){
                finish();
                Log.v("key pressed", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
            }
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            Log.d(TAG, "PAUSE");
            vidView.pause();
            pos=vidView.getCurrentPosition();
            Log.d("POS", String.valueOf(pos));
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResume called");
            vidView.seekTo(pos);
            Log.d("RESUME-POS", String.valueOf(pos));
            vidView.start(); 
        }

    }
```