# VideoView stop playing when fragment goes into pause/stop state

Tags: android, android-studio, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am using a videview to play a video in my fragment when i press the phone home button while video playing and bring the app to foreground again video stops.What is guess is onPause of activity is called that makes the fragment state to reinitialize of some similar reason.Kindly suggest some solution.

Regards:Ali

Comment: Which class are you using for playing Media ?

Comment: `android.widget.VideoView`

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289515/videoview-pausing-and-resuming

Comment: Thats a solution for one videoview what if i have a listview of video views are user can play any number of videos. will this solution be applicable then?Thanks for your response @Agustin