# Android videoview resume not working

Tags: android, android-videoview, resume, pause

I have been working on playing videos using VideoView in Android.

OnPause of fragment i am pausing the video and storing the seektime

```
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();

        if (videoview != null && videoview.isPlaying()) {
            videoview.pause();
            seekTime = videoview.getCurrentPosition();

        }
    }
```

OnResume i am trying to resume the video using -

```
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            videoview.seekTo(seekTime);
            //vvOnboardingVideos.resume();// this is not working for now - need to investigate
            videoview.start();   
        }
```

The video plays from the beginning.

Is there anything i am doing wrong. Please suggest.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289515/videoview-pausing-and-resuming

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reverse order of operations :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    videoview.start();
    videoview.seekTo(seekTime);   
}
```

Comment: This gives the same result - the video starts from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

try this:

save the video position when `onpause()` called

```
// This gets called before onPause
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        stopPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition(); 
        videoView.pause();
        outState.putInt("video_position", stopPosition);
    }
```

Then in your `onCreate()` load the `stopPosition` from the bundle

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle args) {
        super.onCreate(args);
        if( args != null ) {
            stopPosition = args.getInt("video_position");
        }
    }
```

Resume the video using:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("Tag", "onResume");
        videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
        videoView.start(); //Or use videoView.resume() if it doesn't work.
    }
```