# Video does not resume in VideoView

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

Many posts are there for this issue.But the solutions are available for when the activity gets paused. I tried all it doesn't work. My problem is little bit different

> I have a videoview and when the user clicks the videoview ,video will be paused and if he clicks again it should be resumed.

My code snippet in ontouchlistener is,

```
   videopath = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
    imageView = ((VideoView) findViewById(R.id.imageView));
    imageView.setVideoPath(videopath);
    imageView.start();
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                if (layout.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
                    imageView.seekTo(stopPosition);
                    imageView.resume();
                    layout.animate().translationY(-layout.getHeight()).setDuration(500);
                    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    hideSystemUI();
                } else {
                    imageView.pause();
                    stopPosition=imageView.getCurrentPosition();
                    showSystemUI();
                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    layout.animate().translationYBy(layout.getHeight());
                }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I got this solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289515/videoview-pausing-and-resuming) . It doesn't work and simply using resume(); is also not working.

Comment: hello you can handle this with flag too :)

Comment: @SubhashPrajapati could you please explain

Comment: you got click right ?

Comment: @SubhashPrajapati yes,when user clicks,resuming video should be done

Comment: you can use media controller bro

Comment: using mediaController you will able to stop and pause video

Comment: its working or not ?

Comment: @SubhashPrajapati Your solution was correct. It would be great for you if you can explain via example and add post. This is all I can suggest you as of now. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your device looses the time you've stored. You can use MediaPlayer instance, Here how you can use,

```
    VideoView videoView;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    this.mp = mp;
                }
            });

    public void pause(){
        //NOT videoview.pause();
        if (mp != null){
           mp.pause();
        }
    }

    public void resume(){
        //NOT videoview.resume();
        if (mp != null){
           mp.start();
        }   
    }

//This function will be implemented under onClick method
if (!videoView.isPlaying()) {
                 resume();
                 layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 hideSystemUI();//hiding navigationbar
} 
else {//initially layout visibility is GONE
                 pause();
                 stopPosition=videoView.getCurrentPosition();
                 showSystemUI();
                 layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 layout.animate().translationYBy(layout.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: actually I changed the name as videoview to understand it. It is not the problem

Comment: it doesn't work. my problem is "i can pause the  video but it is not reumed"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ;)